# including pages within another jsp with the concept as in php

Tags: php, jsp

adding pages in jsp using the concept in php which is below

```
<?php
    $pg = @$_REQUEST['page'];
    if($pg != "" && file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$pg)) {
         require(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$pg);                 
    } elseif(!file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$pg))
        include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."../404.php");
    else {
        include_once("dash.php");
    }
?>
```

Please help if you have a solution

Comment: Ever heard of Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=jsp+include&oq=jspm+include&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2799j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out
assume your  is as follows: 
`<a href="index.jsp?page=dealer.jsp" class="pointer">Dealer</a>`

**The solution will be as follows**

```
<%
                    String abc=request.getParameter("page"), msg="";
                   // String path = request.getContextPath();

                    if (abc!=null) 
                    {
                    %>
                    <jsp:include page="<%="includes/"+abc %>"/>
                    <%
                    }
                    else if(abc==null)
                    {
                       %>
                    <jsp:include page="<%="includes/"+p+".jsp"%>"/>
                    <% 
                    }
                else{           
                      %>
                    <jsp:include page="<%="includes/404.jsp"%>"/>
                    <% }
                %>
```